# Netbeans project deployed to TomEE intermittent FileNotFoundException

Tags: netbeans, apache-tomee

There is something very weird going on here.  I am using Netbeans 11.3, apache-tomee-webprofile-8.0.1, JDK 10 to build this JEE app, sometimes it works other times right after the build it starts throwing exceptions.  There is no change in the pom.xml yet it just starts misbehaving as I configure things like OpenJPA.  At this point I am not even sure where to look as the behavior is not static or predictable.

TomEE server log exception:

```
17-Apr-2020 00:09:34.632 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No state saving method defined, assuming default server state saving
17-Apr-2020 00:17:01.065 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:282)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:226)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2303)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:41)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:49)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application._ApplicationUtils._traverseListenerList(_ApplicationUtils.java:121)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl$SystemListenerEntry.publish(ApplicationImpl.java:2737)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:634)
        at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:346)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer._dispatchApplicationEvent(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:366)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.destroyFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:410)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(StartupServletContextListener.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5396)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:805)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1425)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1611)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:236)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:307)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:97)
        ... 39 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:233)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /.../WEB-INF/lib/cdi-api-2.0.jar
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:145)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1755)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1220)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:727)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:845)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:245)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:175)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:341)
        ... 46 more
17-Apr-2020 00:17:13.380 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [Faces Servlet] threw exception
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.shoptext</groupId>
   <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
   <version>20200416</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>MyApp</name>

   <properties>
      <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>

   <repositories>
      <repository>  
         <id>prime-repo</id>  
         <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
         <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
         <layout>default</layout>  
      </repository>  
   </repositories>    

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
         <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
         <version>8.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
         <artifactId>bluesky</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.SP1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.12</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
         <artifactId>apache-openjpa</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.1</version>
         <type>zip</type>
         <classifier>binary-nodocs</classifier>
         <scope>provided</scope>         
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax</groupId>
         <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Logging -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.1</version>
      </dependency> 
   </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have changed the actual app name in this question to 'AppName' to just make things a bit easier to read.  Short of that everything else seems to work as expected.  I use Netbeans 11.3 to build and work on this project and I have to recreate it three times now.  I am pretty certain it has nothing to do with the IDE but at this point I am out of ideas.  Have you run into this before?

Comment: Why is it netbeans and  jsf related and not tomee? or cdi (where the error is about!!!)...

Comment: I could not agree more, I just included them because that is the IDE and framework I am using during development.

Comment: @DanielMaldonado [1] I added `tomee` and `cdi` tags for your question to attract a more focused audience, but feel free to remove them if you think they are inappropriate. [2] What is the exact version of TomEE webprofile that you are using?

Comment: apache-tomee-webprofile-8.0.1

Comment: @skomisa: [2] was already in the Q